# How do I write a particular line of Javascript into Jquery syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, hyperlink

I am trying to write a skp nav link script but instead of grabbing the id i want to grab the class. How can I write the following script in jquery syntax to get the class name?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ajax-video").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("currently-playing-title").scrollIntoView();
    });
});
```

Also for some reason the following does not work:

```
$('.videoplayer').scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: If you want animated scrolling into view (only when element is not already in view) you can as well use `.scrolintoview()` [jQuery plugin](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html) (mind lowercase casing). It scrolls a particular element into view while scrolling is animated so user doesn't loose track of their position on the page (no jumping to an arbitrary position that may be up or down from what user sees).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$('.videoplayer')[0].scrollIntoView();
```

`$('.videoplayer')` a jQuery collection and so you can only run jQuery functions on it.  `[0]` accesses the first DOM element in that collection.

Note that if you have more than one element with the `videoplayer` class, you may get unexpected results here.  It's honestly better to use the element ID.

If you have multiple elements with `.videoplayer`, but only one is visible at a time (tabs, etc), you can also try:

```
$('.videoplayer:visible')[0].scrollIntoView()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to obtain the class attribute via the identifier:

```
var className = $('#currently-playing-title').attr('class');
$('.' + className).scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not able to make a comment on cwolves' answer, but jQuery.get() is preferred usage for fetching the DOM ref.

```
$('.videoplayer').get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Using [0] works too, but using .get() results in cleaner looking code, just slightly.

Comment: Actually, that would be `.get(0)`.  `.get()` returns the whole matched set as an array.  Aesthetics aside, `[0]` is identical to `.get(0)` (which is actually what `.get(0)` does internally), there is no "preferred" way to do this.  Technically, `[0]` is faster since there isn't a function call.

Comment: True, true. It is mostly from an aesthetics standpoint, I try to avoid using direct DOM references like that when I am writing jQuery code, hence my preference for get().

Comment: Well without the 0 (zero) it won't work... Aesthetics aside... You need to provide the number to get to actual DOM Element.

Comment: Ah! I stand corrected. Thanks, Rob :) I ought to test more of this stuff in jsfiddle before I go chiming in. ;)